# Выравнивание картинки относительно кнопки

Tags: html, css

Возникла проблема с выравниванием картинки относительно текста кнопки. Мне нужно, чтобы картинка отступала от правого края на 5% на всех разрешениях экрана. Для этого я прибил ее к нему при помощи align="right", но как теперь выровнять картинку  относительно текста(посередине)? Адекватно отображается на десктопной версии, но при изменении разрешения съезжает вверх.
Код

```css
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>События</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
      .pagination{
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      .page-item1{
        display: none;
      }
      .btn{
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      body{
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      .card-img-top{
        height: 200px
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 2% 8%; display: table;">
    <h2 class="caption" style="margin-bottom: 0;">Руководители направлений подготовки</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3" id="success" >
        <div class="card2">
          <div class="card-footer">
            <h3>Фильтр:</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            
            </div>
            <p style="padding-top: 5%; vertical-align: middle">
              <button class="btn1 btn-link" style="text-decoration:none; outline: none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseYear">
                По типу:</button>
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseYear" href="#collapseYear" >
                <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/bendy-and-the-ink-machine/images/9/9f/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0.png/revision/latest?cb=20170925011416&path-prefix=ru" style="width: 8%; margin-right: 5%;" align="right">
              </a>
            </p>
            <div class="col-xl-12" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1); padding-bottom: 0px">
              <div class="collapse multi-collapse show" id="collapseYear">
                <div class="card card-body">
                  <p class="checkbox"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"><label> Конференции</label></p>
                  <p class="checkbox"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"><label> Лекции</label></p>
                  <p class="checkbox"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"><label> Стажировки</label></p>
                  <p class="checkbox"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"><label> Тренинги</label></p>
                  <p class="checkbox"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"><label> Выставки</label></p>
                  <p class="checkbox"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"><label> Дни открытых дверей</label></p>
                  <p class="checkbox"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"><label> Хакатоны</label></p>
                  <p class="checkbox"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"><label> Фестивали</label></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-right" style="padding: 10px">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="run()">Найти</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

:

Вот так выглядит результат: 
 1)Desktop [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2)Меньшее разрешение [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

возьмите текст и картинку в div
и используйте flexbox > row > align-items:center

Answer (score 0):

```css
.checkbox{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```